# Correct PHP Syntax with IF and Echo

Tags: php, list, if-statement, echo

I was hoping I could get some help from you guys. The code below works but I doubt that this is a good way to write the syntax. Especially since it will require an enormous amount of code.

The thing I'm trying to do is create a list which will be populated only if an item has a value. I have already specified if the variable has a value or not (I think that part of the code could use some work as well, but that's a different question). And I've found a way to show or hide the item in the list. But I don't think it's efficient. And that's where I could use some help.

```
            <?php
                if(empty($orderNum))
                    {
                    echo "<li><a href='#' title='Brodit'>Tomte</a></li>";
                    }
                else
                    {
                    echo "<li><a href='unordered.php?SupName=2&SupStatus=3' title='Brodit'>Order ("; echo "$orderNum"; echo ")</a></li>";
                    }
            ?>
```

Comment: Do you have to check alot of those variables? What type do they have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
  if(empty($orderNum)){
    echo "<li><a href='#' title='Brodit'>Tomte</a></li>";
  } else {
    echo "<li><a href='unordered.php?SupName=2&SupStatus=3' title='Brodit'>Order ({$orderNum})</a>  </li>";
  }
?>
```

You can use `"foo {$var} bar"` instead of `"foo ".$var." bar"`. This is (in my opinion) more elegant.

**If the HTML Code gets longer I would prefer:**

```
<?php if(empty($orderNum)): ?>
    <li><a href="#" title="Brodit">Tomte</a></li>
<?php else: ?>
    <li><a href="unordered.php?SupName=2&SupStatus=3"title="Brodit">
      Order (<?php echo $orderNum; ?>)</a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That's perfectly simple! Now to find out how to do this in a more arrayish way :D

Comment: "foo {$array['key']} bar" & "foo {$obj->attr} bar"

Answer (score 4):

You can use php alternative syntax widely used in php templates and suggested in docs like zend manual as well as symfony:

```
<?php if(empty($orderNum)): ?>
    <li><a href="#" title="Brodit">Tomte</a></li>
<?php else: ?>
    <li><a href="unordered.php?SupName=2&SupStatus=3"title="Brodit">
      Order (<?php echo $orderNum; ?>)</a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add another alternative to what was already answered, you could focus on the HTML rather than the PHP:

```
 <?php if(empty($orderNum)) { ?>
     <li><a href='#' title='Brodit'>Tomte</a></li>
 <?php } else {?>
     <li><a href='unordered.php?SupName=2&SupStatus=3' title='Brodit'>Order ("<?php echo $orderNum;?>")</a></li>";
 <?php }?>
```

This especially useful if you want to take advantage of your HTML editor (syntax validation, auto-completion, ...). I would choose this syntax for big chunks of HTML and when working with integrators, because it is less likely that they will screw up the PHP part.

Comment: Depending on complexity of string, this is the best choice. maybe if(): else: endif; would be another way to do it.

Comment: @wormhit How is this cleaner than my answer? By combining PHP and HTML switching between them each line leaves a much greater risk of missing a closing/opening tag and throwing off the entire document.

Comment: @wormhit You said this was "the best choice" while stating that my answer was "really messy". Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jeremy1026 I have been using @wormhit syntax too. It's a matter of preference, and in both case any good IDE should highlight a missing `}` or `endif`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
            if(empty($orderNum))
                {
                echo "<li><a href='#' title='Brodit'>Tomte</a></li>";
                }
            else
                {
                echo "<li><a href='unordered.php?SupName=2&SupStatus=3' title='Brodit'>Order (". $orderNum .")</a></li>";
                }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is assign the string to a variable and then have one echo statement at the end. Also you can do variable substitution in the double quotes. For example:

"Order ($orderNum)"